# Grails and javac opt

Tags: java, grails, javac, conditional-compilation

I'm using grails burning image plugin and it works fine on my Windows development environment and on the linux pre-production server.
Unfortunately, the production server is a FreeBsd server based on openJDK 1.7.0_65.

When I want to upload a picture which is a **'.jpg'** or **'.jpeg'** file, I get a `com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.ImageFormatException`.

After looking on stackoverflow, I found these two posts which seem to say that I have to add `-XDignore.symbol.file` option launching the java compiler.

Source:

- [import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906673/import-com-sun-image-codec-jpeg)
- [Using internal sun classes with javac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065401/using-internal-sun-classes-with-javac/4070685#4070685)

How can I add this option to my grails application?

Comment: If your app is properly deployed, i.e. it is installed into a servlet container, you must add the option to the containers options.

Comment: It's running on tomcat, where can I change container options ? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

This sun package is not supported in OpenJDK. See these links for further reference:

[Issue 28:  fails under OpenJDK-7++](https://code.google.com/p/burningimage/issues/detail?id=28)

[difference between Sun JDK and open JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260446/difference-between-sun-jdk-and-open-jdk)

Sadly, this renders the plugin virtually useless with OpenSDK's.

Edit: What I found as a solution is this plugin:
[hd-image-utils](https://grails.org/plugin/hd-image-utils)

Fair warning thou, it has problems working with CMYK images.

Comment: Not implied from question. I could not find a workaround for this issue. Thought I share my experience and save others some time.

Comment: Not enough reputation to comment on posts other than my own. If you find this exhaustive, please, remove your negative feedback.

Comment: Looking more closely, I'm persuaded that your answer is indeed the only possible answer. I'll remove my other comments. I'm willing to upvote the answer, too, but I can't until it is edited.